# facebook scraper doesn't like some of my pages

Tags: facebook, prestashop, scraper

i have a web shop build on prestashop.
an i am trying to integrate the Like button. and i observed that on some pages it scrapes out a thumbnail on some other pages it does not.
i found out the page that shows us exactly what the scraper sees
so the home page it ok:
http://www.promotion.ro/shop
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fpromotion.ro%2Fshop%2Fen%2F

but a product page does not:
http://promotion.ro/shop/en/christmas-gifts/3009-christmas-decoration-set.html
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fpromotion.ro%2Fshop%2Fen%2Fchristmas-gifts%2F3009-christmas-decoration-set.html

what am i doing wrong?

if i insert the metas, it still doesn't scrape.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any Open Graph meta tags on 'http://promotion.ro/shop/en/christmas-gifts/3009-christmas-decoration-set.html' and neither can Facebook - the page also takes a long time to respond (~10 seconds) which may be slowing down the lint by Facebook when someone likes the page.

Make sure you have a full set of open graph meta tags and it should work OK

Comment: there aren't meta tags on the home page too, and it sees it. also the loading time is the same

Comment: Without the meta tags the images which will be chosen aren't predicatable, you should add the tags or accept that Facebook won't detect your images properly

Comment: According to the debugger the tags are still missing - you have an og:url tag pointing to `http://www.promotion.ro/shop` - so the crawler goes there and picks up the tags from there - the og:url tag should point to the URL that you want the tags read from

Comment: The `http://www.promotion.ro/shop` redirect is invalid because that has a HTTP 301 redirect to `http://www.promotion.ro/shop/` and that page has an og:url meta tag pointing back to `http://www.promotion.ro/shop` so it loops and doesn't update the cache properly

Comment: :url only tells that i want that url to be posted to facebook instead of current page. here's a quote from the docs: og:url - The canonical, permanent URL of the page representing the entity. When you use Open Graph tags, the Like button posts a link to the og:url instead of the URL in the Like button code.